# MariaDB: How to using "INSERT ... SELECT" with WITH statement

Tags: sql, mariadb, with-statement, columnstore

Note: This involves ColumnStore.

At work, we have a big SQL statement that takes too much memory to execute on prod. I'm currently working on reducing the size the query consumes. I've tried using different approaches, but nothing has solved the issue so far, except for `WITH ... AS (...)`, for some reason. However, I need to combine this with an `INSERT INTO ...`.

This is the code I'm trying to get working

```sql
TRUNCATE db1.myTable;

INSERT INTO db1.myTable(`all`, `needed`, `columns`)
(WITH everything AS (
  SELECT all, needed, columns
   FROM db1.mainTable T1
   JOIN db1.secondTable T2
     ON (T1.someCol = T2.someCol)
   JOIN db2.thirdTable T3
     ON (T1.anotherCol = T3.anotherCol)
   LEFT JOIN db1.fourthTable T4
     ON (T4.anotherCol = T1.anotherCol)
   WHERE T2.yetAnotherCol >= (some_SELECT_subquery)
     AND T1.valid = 1
) SELECT * FROM everything);
```

`EXPLAIN (WITH everything AS ...` returns

```sql
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                 | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16000000000000 |                                                 |
|    2 | PRIMARY     | T1                    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000 | Using where with pushed condition               |
|    2 | PRIMARY     | T2                    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | PRIMARY     | T3                    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | PRIMARY     | T4                    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000 | Using where                                     |
|    3 | SUBQUERY    | some_SELECT_subquery  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2000 | Using where with pushed condition               |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0,21 sec)
```

If I only use the `WITH`-statement, I can get it to work. As in, I don't use the `INSERT INTO`. No issues at all, and the query is even faster this way. I also did I quick test with trying to divide the query into several `WITH`s, but gave up since I believe I messed up the syntax. I'm not too good with SQL, and even less so with `JOIN`s(junior developer).

When I combine the `WITH`-statement with an `INSER INTO ...`, MariaDB responds with `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') SELECT * FROM everything)' at line 1`. I've also tried adding a semicolon after `... valid = 1`, merging the two last lines, positioning the open parentheses after `... AS` on a new line, and some other issues I could think of that might be syntax related. No luck.

My current thought is that you can't combine `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` with a `WITH ...`. At least not having the `WITH` at the beginning, where the SELECT should be. This is what I can gather from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

So, in short, my question is: can I combine `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a `WITH`-statement at all? If not, can I achieve something similar  with another technique?

Are there any other ways I can improve the memory utilization of my query? I'd rather not mess with configuration options for MariaDB or Docker, but if that's the only possibility, I'll consider it.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  What error message is in the logs when it gets in trouble?  (I don't think `WITH` is the right approach; let's go back to the original problem.)

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around the query.

Comment: @RickJames `free -m` says 7823. `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` returns `2147483648`. We're using ColumnStore though, if that matters. I'm not sure where the logs are though. We're running MariaDB through a container, and the volume is mounted somewhere. I'm alone at work and can't ask where everything's configured. Sorry

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried that, and the same error message is returned.

Comment: AHA! -- Columnstore is a different beast.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I've added the `EXPLAIN` to the original question.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with `JOINs` in ColumnStore.  I don't happen to know any details there.  (16T is a scary number.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 TRUNCATE db1.myTable;


WITH everything AS (
  SELECT all, needed, columns
   FROM db1.mainTable T1
   JOIN db1.secondTable T2
     ON (T1.someCol = T2.someCol)
   JOIN db2.thirdTable T3
     ON (T1.anotherCol = T3.anotherCol)
   LEFT JOIN db1.fourthTable T4
     ON (T4.anotherCol = T1.anotherCol)
   WHERE T2.yetAnotherCol >= (some_SELECT_subquery)
     AND T1.valid = 1
) INSERT INTO db1.myTable SELECT * FROM everything;
```

Comment: You can actually combine WITH -statement with INSERT INTO SELECT. Been using it with SQL Server. I'm not just sure with MariaDB. Please try above.

Comment: Tried it now, but it returns `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: [sql syntax error ...] near 'INSERT INTO [...]`. I'm reading through the docs now, trying to figure out the correct syntax. Your suggestion seem to be valid, but I'm not completely sure

Comment: I tried your new suggestion, but I still get the same error: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: [...] near 'INSERT INTO ...`

Comment: On MariaDB the order of `WITH INSERT SELECT` is different, it's `INSERT WITH SELECT`, i.e. you have to write `INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2) WITH alias_name AS (SELECT ...) SELECT * FROM alias_name`.

Comment: Note: if anyone needs to support older versions of MariaDB, the above uses CTE support which was added in MariaDB 10.2.1: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/ - so, for older versions, this cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find an answer to my original question, we decided to work around the problem by reducing the amount of data gathered in the subquery. I didn't disclose this in the original question because that wasn't a solution I was aware of when posting the question. We'll just call the SQL from a Python script where we can loop over the week numbers we'd like to fetch.

```
WHERE T2.ID >= (SELECT ID - {week_number} FROM db1.secondTable WHERE NOW() BETWEEN monday AND sunday) AND T1.valid = 1);
```